# Debug Apache Tomcat. Oops! Google Chrome could not connect. Why?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, tomcat, jpda

I have next task: Debug Apache Tomcat in Eclipse.

My steps:

- Run Tomcat: `./startup.sh`
- Check - open in browser localhost:8080/MyProject - SUCCESS.
- in file `catalina.sh` I added next lines:

`export JPDA_ADDRESS=8000`
`export JPDA_TRANSPORT=dt_socket`

- in file `startup.sh`:

I comment this line:

`#exec "$PRGDIR"/"$EXECUTABLE" start "$@"`

and added next line:

`exec "$PRGDIR"/"$EXECUTABLE" jpda start "$@"`

- Run Tomcat: `startup.sh`
- Check - in browser try open localhost:8080/MyProject - FAIL.
  At the next step I will try add settings in Eclipse for remote debug Tomcat, but I have Fail on previous step.

Why did this happen??

Maybe, it is depends on OS type? I use Ubuntu 11.10...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) No pun intended: did you stop tomcat after modifying .sh files and before runing startup.sh?

2.) Check tomcat log for errors.

3.) I run Tomcat on debug this way:

- Created a MyCatalinaStart.sh (bat on windows) with the following

> export JPDA_ADDRESS=8000
>
> export JPDA_TRANSPORT=dt_socket
>
> export JPDA_SUSPEND=n
>
> catalina.sh jpda start

- Started Tomcat from it. The sh or bat files require NO modification, they came ready to receive inputs

Comment: Some sensitive people may think "hey, i'm not retarded, etc" or such.